# Are there more examples of this method in calculus?

Tags: calculus

One of my absolute favorite derivations in math is the calculation of the sum of the alternating harmonic series, $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \dots$, which is done by considering the function $f(x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \dots$ and noticing that $f'(x) = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 = \frac{1}{1+x}$ implying $f(x) = \ln(1+x)$ and thus the series converges to $\ln(1+1) = \ln(2)$.

The method here of deriving a formula for an unknown function by taking its derivative and gaining more information about the original function can also be used to derive $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$. If $f(\theta) = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$, then $f'(\theta) = if(\theta)$, which solves to $f(\theta) = e^{i\theta}$.

My question is, are there more examples of this technique, or is it a coincidence that it worked so well in these two cases?

Comment: Similar stuff occurs a lot of the time if you look into things involving formal power series (combinatorics makes a lot of use of this with generating functions). Another common use case that comes to mind is as an integration technique with Feynman integration.

Comment: The technique you used is uniqueness of the solution of the ODE. This can be used to define the matrix exponential and prove some of its properties. Also the differentiation technique can be used to extract the moments of a random variable from its characteristic function.

Comment: $1 - x + x^2 - x^3 = \frac{1}{1+x}$ only if $-1<x<1$, so $f(1)=\ln{(1+1)}$ needs to be justified.

Answer (score 3):

$(1+x^2)^{-1}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\dots$,
$\arctan x=\int(1+x^2)^{-1}\,dx=x-(x^3/3)+(x^5/5)-(x^7/7)+\cdots$
$\pi/4=\arctan1=1-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)+\cdots$.

Another example (that has come up often on this site): show that
$$
\sum_1^{\infty}{n\over2^n}={1\over2}+{2\over4}+{3\over8}+{4\over16}+{5\over32}+\cdots=2.
$$
Solution: let $f(x)=\sum_1^{\infty}nx^n$, so we want to show $f(1/2)=2$. Then $x^{-1}f(x)=\sum_1^{\infty}nx^{n-1}$ is the derivative of $\sum_1^{\infty}x^n=x/(1-x)$. The derivative of $x/(1-x)$ is $(1-x)^{-2}$, so $f(x)=x(1-x)^{-2}$, and $f(1/2)=2$.